# Phone coupler with excellent isolation

Tags: hardware, radio

For recording phone interviews, we have an [Excalibur HC-1](http://www.bswusa.com/proditem.asp?item=HC-1) phone coupler.
[image: Excalibur HC-1]

Trouble is, there isn't much isolation between send and receive.  When doing interviews, if we send it audio, it comes back on the receive all distorted and what not.

Is there a way we can fix this problem with our current coupler, or is there a cheap alternative available?  $150 is our budget.  This is for an internet radio station.

Comment: Community: feel free to disagree, but in my opinion this question does not belong on this site. It is very specific, "localized" in SE words, and apart from being used for internet radio broadcasting, not really 'producing/recording/pro audio' related.

Comment: @Pelle, I completely disagree.  Think of it this way.  If the title were to be worded "recording a track from a telephone, and having quality problems" with nearly the exact same content, it would fall dead center into allowed questions.  It is also definitely pro-audio oriented.  Radio production is not pro-audio?  Either way, this should be disputed in meta, and not here.

Comment: Good points. Both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a **telephone hybrid**. Excalibur makes one called the **HA-1**:

[image: Excalibur HA-1 Hybrid Adapter]

There are a number of others, like the **Broadcast Tools TT1** (still within your budget) and the **JK Audio AutoHybrid** (slightly outside your budget).

Trans-hybrid loss (isolation) is measured in decibels, 20db is a fairly standard number to look for. Cost goes up for greater loss; state-of-the-art hybrids use DSPs.